# AWS boto filters

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto

Below is the JSON result (for one volume) I get from running `aws ec2 describe-volumes`:

```
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1a", 
    "Attachments": [
        {
            "AttachTime": "2015-02-23T15:01:37.000Z", 
            "InstanceId": "i-abcd1234", 
            "VolumeId": "vol-pqrs1234", 
            "State": "attached", 
            "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
            "Device": "/dev/xvda"
        }
    ], 
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Value": "on", 
            "Key": "snapshot"
        }, 
        {
            "Value": "srv001: /", 
            "Key": "Name"
        }
    ], 
    "Encrypted": false, 
    "VolumeType": "gp2", 
    "VolumeId": "vol-pqrs1234", 
    "State": "in-use", 
    "Iops": 24, 
    "SnapshotId": "snap-klmn1234", 
    "CreateTime": "2015-02-23T15:01:37.000Z", 
    "Size": 8
},
```

Using Python Boto, I can get a list of volume ids, using filters.

```
volumes = conn.get_all_volumes(filters={"tag:snapshot" : "on"})
```

I would like to filter on "State: in-use" and possibly other values, and do something similar for snapshots. I can't find the proper filter names. Filters like "state" or "attachment.state" are not allowed:

```
The filter 'attachment.state' is invalid
```

**What are the proper filter names, or where can I find them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can call the [ec2-describe-snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSnapshots.html) using the VolumeId and get more info about the snapshots from this volume.

Comment: And for volumes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeVolumes.html Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The original poster asked about `aws ec2 describe-volumes` which is a different tool than `ec2-describe-volumes`. The info on the awscli describe-volumes can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html).

With reference to the OP's question, here's the list of filters:

--filters (list)

```
One or more filters.

    attachment.attach-time - The time stamp when the attachment initiated.
    attachment.delete-on-termination - Whether the volume is deleted on instance termination.
    attachment.device - The device name that is exposed to the instance (for example, /dev/sda1 ).
    attachment.instance-id - The ID of the instance the volume is attached to.
    attachment.status - The attachment state (attaching | attached | detaching | detached ).
    availability-zone - The Availability Zone in which the volume was created.
    create-time - The time stamp when the volume was created.
    encrypted - The encryption status of the volume.
    size - The size of the volume, in GiB.
    snapshot-id - The snapshot from which the volume was created.
    status - The status of the volume (creating | available | in-use | deleting | deleted | error ).
    tag :key =*value* - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource.
    tag-key - The key of a tag assigned to the resource. This filter is independent of the tag-value filter. For example, if you use both the filter "tag-key=Purpose" and the filter "tag-value=X", you get any resources assigned both the tag key Purpose (regardless of what the tag's value is), and the tag value X (regardless of what the tag's key is). If you want to list only resources where Purpose is X, see the tag :key =*value* filter.
    tag-value - The value of a tag assigned to the resource. This filter is independent of the tag-key filter.
    volume-id - The volume ID.
    volume-type - The Amazon EBS volume type. This can be gp2 for General Purpose (SSD) volumes, io1 for Provisioned IOPS (SSD) volumes, or standard for Magnetic volumes.
```

Comment: You're right that Lucas pointed to snapshots, not volumes, but it was enough to help me on the way, and that's all I needed in this case.

Comment: I was also trying to distinguish between the [awscli tools](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and the community-contributed [EC2 Command line tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/Welcome.html)